# NoUiSlider On Event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgrowl, nouislider

Im displaying notifications each time i change a value using a slider, the first change creates one notification but then after that it creates multiple notification instead of one. Any ideas how i can stop this? Thank you for any help i have included my code below.

Each time the slider is moved this event fires.

```
$("#single-slider").on({

        change: function () {
            $("#single-slider").Link('lower').to(Notification);
        }
    });
```

It is bound to my notification function which lets me pass values in and display a message as seen below.

```
function Notification(value, type) {
console.log(value);
var tFormat = value;
$.jGrowl(' Refresh rate for ' + type + ' changed to ' + tFormat, { life: 10000, header: '<i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-2x"></i>' });
```

}

However instead of creating one notification it is creating multiple notifications.

Comment: You're probably binding the change event inside another event, doesn't the slider you're using have a `change` event built in?

Comment: it does, the change: function is the sliders change event. That's why i couldn't understand why it was firing multiple times.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2py6oz04/ I assume you are adding the listener more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is fine (http://jsfiddle.net/2py6oz04/). You are probably adding the listener more than once.

Try using

```
$('#single-slider').off("change");
```

Before

```
$("#single-slider").on({
    change: function () {
        $("#single-slider").Link('lower').to(Notification);
    }
});
```

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/2py6oz04/1/
I add a listener, take it off and add it again. If you remove the  `off` line, you get two alerts.

Also, add a console.log() before the `$("#single-slider").on` to log how many times it's added. Ideally, you should fix the root problem and not just turn the existing listener off.